# How can I see the ingredients for equipment in Atelier Totori?

Tags: atelier-totori

When crafting equipment in *Atelier Totori* (North American version), there seems to be no indication of which kind of ingot or cloth (e.g. Muffcot, Silkis, Polywool) it requires; only an indication of whether I can craft it or not.

Am I missing something? Is there a button I can press to view the ingredients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no indication in the game itself.

## Weapons

Weapons for all characters follow the same pattern.

- Ingot / Tinc
- Tinc / Dry Metal / Ster Metal
- Goldstein / Silvatite
- Platine
- Halmolium

## Clothing

There is no such regularity for the clothing, so there's no way to provide the ingredients list without spoiling all the clothing in the game. I also can't find any reference for the original, uncrafted names of each piece.

> **Alchemy Costume** - Cloth / Muffcot
>  **Normal Threads** - Muffcot / Silkis
>  **Traveler's Wear** - Silkis / Polywool / Nylonfeather
>  **Port Outfit** - Polywool / Nylonfeather / Tanbeash
>  **Angel Robe** - Scale Cloth
>  **Ancient Garb** - Velvetis
>  **Adventure Wear** - Cloth / Muffcot
>  **Fancy Armor** - Muffcot / Silkis
>  **Feather Chain** - Silkis / Polywool / Nylonfeather
>  **Dragon Wear** - Nylonfeather / Tanbeash
>  **Blessed Costume** - Scale Cloth
>  **Hero Mail** - Velvetis
>  **Lady Plate** - Silkis / Polywool
>  **Battle Mail** - Nylonfeather / Tanbeash
>  **Maiden Armor** - Scale Cloth
>  **Valkyrie Cloth** - Velvetis
>  **Rose Maiden** - Polywool / Nylonfeather / Tanbeash
>  **Gorgeous Dress** - Scale Cloth
>  **Saint Robe** - Velvetis
>  **Leather Coat** - Muffcot / Silkis / Polywool
>  **Dragoon Cape** - Scale Cloth / Tanbeash
>  **Full Metal Jacket** - Nylonfeather / Tanbeash
>  **Solar Cloak** - Scale Cloth
>  **Heroic Cape** - Velvetis
>  **Phantom Thief** - Tanbeash / Nylonfeather
>  **Fighter's Garb** - Nylonfeather / Tanbeash
>  **Scholar's Robe** - Cloth / Muffcot
>  **Knight's Uniform** - Muffcot / Silkis / Polywool
>  **Iron Chef Outfit** - Scale Cloth / Velvetis